# How to read these journal entries after failed boot?

Tags: arch-linux, boot, freeze, bios, journalctl

My system failed to boot several times today.
After completely disconnecting it from power, I managed to get it back on, luckily, but I'd like to comprehend what has happened.

From a user's point of view, it was like this:
I turn on the PC, the fans are noisier than usual and the boot process would get stuck sometimes at the boot screen, sometimes after GRUB and sometimes in the short timespan where the image of my graphics card is displayed.

I checked the journal and discovered the following lines that didn't appear before. Here's the complete journal entry of one of the failed boots. The other entries look similar.

```
-- Boot 4c3326651829453c89c08358e88b8071 --
Jan 22 01:42:53 hostname kernel: Linux version 5.10.9-arch1-1 (linux@archlinux) (gcc (GCC) 10.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.35.1) #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue, 19 Jan 2021 22:06:06 +0000
Jan 22 01:42:53 hostname kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=d825234f-4397-494f-9c61-e719a008ecbd rw loglevel=3 quiet
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname kernel: input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input15
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname kernel: input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input16
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname kernel: input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input17
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname kernel: input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input18
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname kernel: input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input19
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname kernel: input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=11 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input20
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname kernel: input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=12 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input21
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname kernel: input: HD-Audio Generic Front Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0/input22
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname kernel: input: HD-Audio Generic Rear Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0/input23
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname kernel: input: HD-Audio Generic Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0/input24
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname kernel: input: HD-Audio Generic Line Out as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0/input25
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname audit[425]: NETFILTER_CFG table=filter family=10 entries=144 op=xt_replace pid=425 comm="ip6tables-resto"
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname kernel: input: HD-Audio Generic Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0/input26
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname kernel: EDAC amd64: F15h detected (node 0).
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname kernel: EDAC amd64: Error: F1 not found: device 0x1601 (broken BIOS?)
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname audit[426]: NETFILTER_CFG table=filter family=10 entries=160 op=xt_replace pid=426 comm="ip6tables-resto"
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname systemd-udevd[258]: controlC0: Process '/usr/bin/alsactl restore 0' failed with exit code 99.
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in First Boot Wizard being skipped.
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in File System Check on Root Device being skipped.
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Rebuild Hardware Database being skipped.
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Repartition Root Disk being skipped.
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Create System Users being skipped.
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname audit[435]: NETFILTER_CFG table=filter family=10 entries=168 op=xt_replace pid=435 comm="ip6tables-resto"
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname kernel: EDAC amd64: F15h detected (node 0).
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname kernel: EDAC amd64: Error: F1 not found: device 0x1601 (broken BIOS?)
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname systemd[1]: Finished CLI Netfilter Manager.
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=ufw comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname kernel: EDAC amd64: F15h detected (node 0).
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname kernel: EDAC amd64: Error: F1 not found: device 0x1601 (broken BIOS?)
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname kernel: nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname kernel: Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname kernel: nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 237
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname kernel: 
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname kernel: nvidia 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname kernel: NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  460.32.03  Sun Dec 27 19:00:34 UTC 2020
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname systemd-udevd[267]: controlC1: Process '/usr/bin/alsactl restore 1' failed with exit code 99.
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in First Boot Wizard being skipped.
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in File System Check on Root Device being skipped.
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Rebuild Hardware Database being skipped.
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Repartition Root Disk being skipped.
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Create System Users being skipped.
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname kernel: random: crng init done
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname kernel: random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname systemd[1]: Finished Load/Save Random Seed.
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-random-seed comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in First Boot Complete being skipped.
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname kernel: nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  460.32.03  Sun Dec 27 18:51:11 UTC 2020
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname kernel: [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Loading driver
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname kernel: [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20160202 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname systemd[1]: Created slice system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice.
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video0...
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname systemd[1]: Finished Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video0.
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? termi>
Jan 22 01:38:18 hostname kernel: ata2: softreset failed (1st FIS failed)
Jan 22 01:38:28 hostname kernel: ata2: softreset failed (1st FIS failed)
```

Note the timestamps. These jumps back to the past happened several times. Is that normal behavior or already an indication for problems?
I learned that they should always be in the correct time sequence.
When I closed and reopened the journal, the journal entries were ordered correctly though, regarding their timestamps.

The very first boot entry of this failing series is far longer (probably due to the soft reset).
I noticed the following entries in addition to the above:

```
    Jan 22 01:38:08 hostname kernel: ACPI BIOS Warning (bug): Optional FADT field Pm2ControlBlock has valid Length but zero Address: 0x0000000000000000/0x1 (20200925/tbfadt-615)
    ...
    Jan 22 01:38:08 hostname kernel: ata2.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x30000 SErr 0x0 action 0x6
    Jan 22 01:38:08 hostname kernel: ata2.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
    Jan 22 01:38:08 hostname kernel: ata2.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
    Jan 22 01:38:08 hostname kernel: ata2.00: cmd 60/78:80:88:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 16 ncq dma 61440 in
                                             res 43/84:78:f0:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x410 (ATA bus error) <F>
    Jan 22 01:38:08 hostname kernel: ata2.00: status: { DRDY SENSE ERR }
    Jan 22 01:38:08 hostname kernel: ata2.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
    Jan 22 01:38:08 hostname kernel: ata2: hard resetting link
    Jan 22 01:38:08 hostname kernel: ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
    Jan 22 01:38:08 hostname kernel: ata2.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
    Jan 22 01:38:08 hostname kernel: ata2.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
    Jan 22 01:38:08 hostname kernel: ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
    Jan 22 01:38:08 hostname kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#16 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=1s
    Jan 22 01:38:08 hostname kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#16 Sense Key : Aborted Command [current] 
    Jan 22 01:38:08 hostname kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#16 Add. Sense: Scsi parity error
    Jan 22 01:38:08 hostname kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#16 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 88 00 00 78 00
    Jan 22 01:38:08 hostname kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 136 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
```

I suspect the power cord as the culprit as I remember having had boot problems before that I could fix with reconnecting the power cord. Is there anyone here that can help me understand these logs better.

**I am especially curious about the entries that refer to the BIOS. Without knowing the circumstances, what information can you extract from that?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a modern multi-core processor and your distribution uses `systemd`. As a result, at boot time, many things will happen in parallel, sometimes with no fixed ordering. Some of the log messages might be slightly out of order with each other, if they used different routes (native `systemd` journaling vs. the kernel's audit subsystem vs. the syslog system calls).

I'll go through the messages in mostly-sequential order, but grouping some similar messages together.

```
Jan 22 01:42:53 hostname kernel: Linux version 5.10.9-arch1-1 (linux@archlinux) (gcc (GCC) 10.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.35.1) #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue, 19 Jan 2021 22:06:06 +0000
Jan 22 01:42:53 hostname kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=d825234f-4397-494f-9c61-e719a008ecbd rw loglevel=3 quiet
```

These are normally the very first lines the Linux kernel outputs right after the it has begun executing. At this point, the system clock is just using the time value the system firmware initialized it to, which usually originates from the battery-backed clock chip. Note the `loglevel=3 quiet` kernel options: these will silence a lot of early boot messages, so quite a lot can happen after this and before the next messages.

```
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname kernel: input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input15
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname kernel: input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input16
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname kernel: input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input17
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname kernel: input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input18
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname kernel: input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input19
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname kernel: input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=11 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input20
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname kernel: input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=12 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input21
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname kernel: input: HD-Audio Generic Front Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0/input22
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname kernel: input: HD-Audio Generic Rear Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0/input23
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname kernel: input: HD-Audio Generic Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0/input24
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname kernel: input: HD-Audio Generic Line Out as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0/input25
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname kernel: input: HD-Audio Generic Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0/input26
```

These messages are from the input subsystem registering the plug detection circuits on various audio connectors as inputs. This means the actual sound drivers have already been loaded at this point. Sound chips are not usually considered "essential hardware", so their drivers are not typically built into the kernel and not always even included in the initramfs, so at this point we are probably quite a bit farther along the boot process.

It is possible that the boot process may have already activated the network interface(s) and fetched more accurate time information from an NTP server, which might explain the apparent time jump backwards. Or the boot process might take the time of the last disk write operation as the best guess of the current time, if no battery-backed clock is available and NTP servers cannot be reached yet.

```
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname audit[425]: NETFILTER_CFG table=filter family=10 entries=144 op=xt_replace pid=425 comm="ip6tables-resto"
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname audit[426]: NETFILTER_CFG table=filter family=10 entries=160 op=xt_replace pid=426 comm="ip6tables-resto"
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname audit[435]: NETFILTER_CFG table=filter family=10 entries=168 op=xt_replace pid=435 comm="ip6tables-resto"
```

Something (probably `ip6tables-restore`) is causing IPv6 netfilter rules to be added.

```
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname kernel: EDAC amd64: F15h detected (node 0).
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname kernel: EDAC amd64: Error: F1 not found: device 0x1601 (broken BIOS?)
```

These messages are from the EDAC (Error Detection And Correction) subsystem. It's mostly useful on systems with ECC error-correcting memory only (i.e. servers and possibly high-grade workstations). Your processor seems to have the necessary features to work with ECC memory, but your system firmware apparently does not have the necessary information for the EDAC subsystem to map memory/bus errors to a physical component (e.g. a memory module slot). Perhaps your motherboard is not capable of using ECC memory? If that's true, then the EDAC subsystem might not be useful to you, and you could blacklist the EDAC modules to skip loading them at all.

```
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname systemd-udevd[258]: controlC0: Process '/usr/bin/alsactl restore 0' failed with exit code 99.
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname systemd-udevd[267]: controlC1: Process '/usr/bin/alsactl restore 1' failed with exit code 99.
```

For some reason, the attempts to restore sound card volume settings failed for both the motherboard's integrated sound chip and the GPU's HDMI/DP connectors. Perhaps because `alsactl store` has never been used to persistently store the current settings? This might be important only if you use raw ALSA and/or text mode: most GUI desktop environments and/or Pulseaudio will usually override the ALSA volume settings by user-specific settings anyway.

```
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in First Boot Wizard being skipped.
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in File System Check on Root Device being skipped.
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Rebuild Hardware Database being skipped.
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Repartition Root Disk being skipped.
Jan 22 01:38:09 hostname systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Create System Users being skipped.
```

`systemd` is skipping some conditional boot items, as the requisite conditions are not satisfied.

```
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname kernel: nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname kernel: Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname kernel: nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 237
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname kernel: 
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname kernel: nvidia 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname kernel: NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  460.32.03  Sun Dec 27 19:00:34 UTC 2020
```

The proprietary NVIDIA GPU driver is being loaded.

```
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-random-seed comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
```

This looks like the root filesystem is mounted and the "real" systemd start-up is confirmed by the audit subsystem. Before this point, the boot process was handled by a "mini-systemd" within the initramfs. This might explain why some messages seem to be repeated: the initramfs mini-systemd made those checks once, and now the real systemd does them again.

```
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname kernel: random: crng init done
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname kernel: random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname systemd[1]: Finished Load/Save Random Seed.
```

`systemd` has restored the random seed from the last startup or orderly shutdown.

```
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname kernel: nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  460.32.03  Sun Dec 27 18:51:11 UTC 2020
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname kernel: [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Loading driver
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname kernel: [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20160202 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
```

More components of the proprietary NVIDIA GPU driver are being started.

```
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname systemd[1]: Created slice system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice.
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video0...
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname systemd[1]: Finished Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video0.
Jan 22 01:38:10 hostname audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? termi>
```

The firmware ACPI tables include a backlight control interface, and `systemd` is starting up a service that remembers the current backlight setting from one boot to the next.

```
Jan 22 01:38:18 hostname kernel: ata2: softreset failed (1st FIS failed)
Jan 22 01:38:28 hostname kernel: ata2: softreset failed (1st FIS failed)
```

This suggests problems with the second SATA device. Your second snippet seems to have more information about this.

From the second snippet:

```
Jan 22 01:38:08 hostname kernel: ACPI BIOS Warning (bug): Optional FADT field Pm2ControlBlock has valid Length but zero Address: 0x0000000000000000/0x1 (20200925/tbfadt-615)
```

Your ACPI system firmware has incomplete power management information. A BIOS update might fix this, but since it's just a warning, the kernel can live with the problem.

```
Jan 22 01:38:08 hostname kernel: ata2.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x30000 SErr 0x0 action 0x6
Jan 22 01:38:08 hostname kernel: ata2.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
Jan 22 01:38:08 hostname kernel: ata2.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Jan 22 01:38:08 hostname kernel: ata2.00: cmd 60/78:80:88:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 16 ncq dma 61440 in
                                         res 43/84:78:f0:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x410 (ATA bus error) <F>
Jan 22 01:38:08 hostname kernel: ata2.00: status: { DRDY SENSE ERR }
Jan 22 01:38:08 hostname kernel: ata2.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
Jan 22 01:38:08 hostname kernel: ata2: hard resetting link
Jan 22 01:38:08 hostname kernel: ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Jan 22 01:38:08 hostname kernel: ata2.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
Jan 22 01:38:08 hostname kernel: ata2.00: NCQ Send/Recv Log not supported
Jan 22 01:38:08 hostname kernel: ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
Jan 22 01:38:08 hostname kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#16 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=1s
Jan 22 01:38:08 hostname kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#16 Sense Key : Aborted Command [current] 
Jan 22 01:38:08 hostname kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#16 Add. Sense: Scsi parity error
Jan 22 01:38:08 hostname kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#16 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 88 00 00 78 00
Jan 22 01:38:08 hostname kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 136 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
```

This indicates a data transfer error from your `/dev/sdb` disk. This might be caused by a bad SATA cable or connector, so you might first try moving the disk to a different SATA port or replacing the cable first. If those things won't help, it might be necessary to replace the disk. If the fault seems to come and go, make an extra backup of that disk ASAP.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the great answer! It helps me a lot understanding what is happening, and I will keep your considerations in mind when this problem reoccurs another time. Luckily, sdb is usually not in usage and there is no need for me to backup that drive. I can live with unpluging it when it breaks. I will consider changing the log level in order to see more of the boot events the next time some strange errors occur :)
I also considered the time difference might be a result of battery clock vs NTP, but I wasn't sure. So thanks for confirming this point.

Comment: So, is it possible to read from this log that the system would fail booting or are the logs missing so much information due to the loglevel, that it is not possible to tell?